# Why is DotLiquid or Azure Logic Apps automatically converting my date field?

Tags: liquid, azure-logic-apps, dotliquid

I have a liquid template that includes a date field, which I am not using any filters on at all, but it's getting converted from `2020-04-11T22:02:11Z` UTC to `4/11/2020 10:02:11 PM`. Is this expected behavior of DotLiquid or Azure Logic Apps? How can I prevent it from doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I met the same problem in the past, liquid will convert the date time from `2020-04-11T22:02:11Z` to `4/11/2020 10:02:11 PM` automatically even if it is a string. As a workaround, we can use date format to convert it to the original date time.

For example, I have a json as below:

```
{
    "datetime": "2020-04-11T22:02:11Z"
}
```

We can use the liquid map like this:

```
{
    "datetime":"{{content.datetime | Date: "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ"}}"
}
```

After that, we can get the original date format as `2020-04-11T22:02:11Z`.

Hope it helps~

Comment: Thanks, Hury. Are you using DotLiquid or Logic Apps or just plain liquid?

Comment: @JoeyEng I test it in logic app with integration account (liquid map).

Comment: K, because I tested with plain liquid and it wasn't auto converting the date format. I think this might be DotLiquid since that's what Logic Apps uses, but just a guess.

Comment: [DotLiquid](https://github.com/dotliquid/dotliquid/wiki/DotLiquid-Syntax-Compatibility) uses the [standard Microsoft date time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#the-round-trip-o-o-format-specifier) as default so you can use the 'O' format string to output ISO 8601 compliant date-time properties. For example: `"dateTime": "{{content.dateTime | Date: 'O'}}"`

Answer (score 0):

If you're running DotLiquid locally and using the Newtonsoft JSON deserializer then you can tell it not to parse date-time strings and to leave them as strings:

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None
};
```

The Azure Logic Apps workflow engine seems to mirror this behaviour as my date-time strings aren't changed.